# How to append to CSV in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I've got below code:

```
def self.to_csv(options = {})
    CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
      csv << %w{ id email title first_name last_name position work_phone company state industry mobile origin terms events roles booths }
      all.each do |user|
        events = '', roles = '', booths = ''
        events = user.events.first.name.to_s if user.events.present?
        roles = user.roles.first.name.to_s if user.roles.present?
        booths = user.booths.first.name.to_s if user.booths.present?
        csv << user.attributes.values_at("id", "email", "title", "first_name", "last_name", "position", "work_phone", "company", "state", "industry", "mobile", "origin", "terms")
        csv << events
        csv << roles
        csv << booths
      end
    end
  end
```

I want to be able to generate csv and add those values in the extra columns but I'm getting `undefined method 'map' for "admin":String` error.

Is there a way to append this to the csv on the same row?

Comment: what's the line# of the erro ?

Comment: `csv << roles` because it has a value

Comment: I don't see a StringIO object in this code.  What are you talking about when you say "stringIO"?

Answer (score 1):

[`CSV#<<`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-i-3C-3C) says :

> The primary write method for wrapped Strings and IOs, row (an **Array** or **CSV::Row**) is converted to CSV and appended to the data source. When a CSV::Row is passed, only the row’s fields() are appended to the output.

But you are passing *stirngs*. see below :

```
csv << events # string
csv << roles  # string
csv << booths # string
```

Tried to replicate the erro :

```
require 'csv'

a = CSV.generate("") do |csv|
  csv << "foo"
end
#  `<<': undefined method `map' for "foo":String (NoMethodError)
```

Here is a fix :

```
require 'csv'

a = CSV.generate("") do |csv|
  csv << ["foo"] # just wrapped the string into an Array as doc is saying.
end
a # => "foo\n"
```

Write your code as :

```
def self.to_csv(options = {})
  CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
    csv << %w{ id email title first_name last_name position work_phone company state industry mobile origin terms events roles booths }
    all.each do |user|
      ary = %w[events,roles,booths].map do |item|
        user.send(item).first.name if user.send(item).present?
      end
      row = user.attributes.values_at("id", "email", "title", "first_name", "last_name", "position", "work_phone", "company", "state", "industry", "mobile", "origin", "terms")
      row.push(*ary)
      csv << row 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Arup, but I want this on the same row for all they append on the second, third and forth rows

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper Your code is not clear to tell you what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

When you append to csv it's expecting an array that represents a row or a CSV::Row object. First, build the array, then append that to csv as follows:

```
row = user.attributes.values_at("id", "email", "title", "first_name", "last_name", "position", "work_phone", "company", "state", "industry", "mobile", "origin", "terms")
row << events
row << roles
row << booths
csv << row
```

Comment: Since my answer is technically correct I'd like to request comments to help me avoid whatever mistake has lead to my answer being moderated down.

Comment: Were the downvotes before you added the comment at the top?  If so maybe the lack of explanation was the reason.

Comment: Yes, at least one of them was. I think the other may have been after I added it, but I'm not sure. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @TimPeters You are right, as far as I can remember , he add the code fragment only. No explanation was there. I am aware of this, as I was preparing my answer at that time. After 15 mins, I have seen the lines on the top of the code.